# Practice Questions Lambert W function/Product Log

Tags: lambert-w

I am not too sure if I should be posting this, if it's not appropriate, I'll delete it as soon as I can. I have learnt about the Lambert W function recently (also called product log) and I was looking for some practice questions online. With most topics, I've found a prolific amount of pdfs full of problems and well explained answers, I imagine these would have been very arduous to write up, and am very thankful to the people who've written them. With the Lambert function though, I could only really find a couple youtube videos demonstrating individual problems and solutions. Unfortunately it was not enough for me to feel confident with my knowledge. I'm not sure how esoteric of a topic this is, but I am wondering if anyone has or knows where I could find some practice problems for the Lambert function. Again, I am sorry if this is not an appropriate question, thank you for reading :)

Comment: Just look up a good book on this topic online, and use a pdf of that as your resource.

Comment: On this search bar, just type *Lambert function* : $3331$ entries.

Comment: [Lambert's W Function in Maple](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2457313_Lambert%27s_W_Function_in_Maple).